Which ability checks are rolled for a shove attack?
I've been looking at the shoving rules. I'm slightly confused on the 'contested' wording and which skills are rolled. The rules say:

Instead of making an attack roll, you make a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check (the target chooses the ability to use).

My character has a better Athletics modifier, so as a player I prefer to roll an Athletics check, but it says that the target chooses which ability to use.
Does that mean that I, the player, can roll Athletics (which might get me a higher outcome) and the target can choose to contest with their Acrobatics (which for them might be better), which would make it an Athletics vs. Acrobatics test? Or does it mean I declare I'm going to try and shove and the target chooses if I roll Athletics or Acrobatics and then contests back with their own score?
The confusion for me is I thought 'contested' meant a like-for-like roll-off.

Contests are described on page 174 of the Player's Handbook or in D&D Beyond's basic rules.

Both participants in a contest make ability checks appropriate to their efforts. They apply all appropriate bonuses and penalties, but instead of comparing the total to a DC. they compare the totals of their two checks. The participant with the higher check total wins the contest.

You said you thought a contest would mean "a like-for-like roll off", which I'm understanding to mean that you expected a contest to always have both participants rolling the same ability score and skill.
That is not correct. Each party's roll must only be appropriate to their effort. Some very common examples of contests would be my Dexterity (Stealth) versus your Wisdom (Perception) -- I'm hiding, do you notice me? -- or my Charisma (Deception) versus your Wisdom (Insight) -- I'm lying, do you realize it?
You don't even have to make the two rolls at the same time.  The rules for Hiding (sidebar at the end of the Dexterity section) say:

When you try to hide, make a Dexterity (Stealth) check. Until you are discovered or you stop hiding, that check's total is contested by the Wisdom (Perception) check of any creature that actively searches for signs of your presence.

So in that case, you're going to roll Stealth at one point, and later on that result may be contested by several creatures at different times, maybe many minutes later.
In a shove, you -- as the active character attempting to shove -- always make a Strength (Athletics) check. There's no option on that. The target you are trying to shove can choose whether they want to counter with their own Strength (Athletics) in a contest of raw power, or they can try to evade by using Dexterity (Acrobatics) to keep their balance, slip away from the shove, etc. A minotaur will naturally resist an attempt to shove them differently than a monk will.

If you are the party trying to Shove someone, then you roll Athletics for this attempt, there is no wiggle room here or space for anyone to choose anything different, the attacker always rolls Athletics. The enemy that is trying to defend against your Shove gets to choose whether to roll Athletics or Acrobatics as the defence.
Their choice doesn't influence what you roll, your roll is always Athletics:

If they decide to also roll Athletics, then the contested check is
your Athletics vs their Athletics.
If they decide to roll Acrobatics, then it's your Athletics vs their Acrobatics.

The point here is that a contested check is indeed a "roll off" where the higher roll wins but it doesn't mean that both participants need to use the same ability for it.
